# '<script>' tag is changed to '<a>' when configuring Cookie Notice

Tags: plugins

I'm using WP 5.2.2 and trying to configure a cookie notice banner. I'm using the popular [Cookie Notice](https://dfactory.eu/products/cookie-notice/?utm_source=cookie-notice-settings) plugin (v1.2.46).

My problem comes that when I configure the Google Analytics script (the one to be inserted when the user accepts the use of cookies), when saving changes the code is changed from

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[];function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};gtag('js',new Date());gtag('config','UA-XXXXXXXX-X');</script>
```

to

```
<a href="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-X">https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-X</a>
<script>window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[];function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};gtag('js',new Date());gtag('config','UA-XXXXXXXX-X');</script>
```

Obviously it makes my site not being tracked by GA.

I've being looking around for a solution and I haven't been able to find one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the problem into a local server in order to debug the plugin and it worked flawlessly. When looking at the difference between both installations I noticed this one, related to JetPack (v7.4.1), in JP / Writing / Composing:

> Compose using shortcodes to embed media from popular sites

Disabling such option the Cookie Notice plugin started to save the snippet correctly.